# Tower of Hanoi-Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, pseudocode, towers-of-hanoi

I am really new using Haskell. I was trying to write an h4 function, which will calculate the minimum steps to finish the tower of Hanoi using 4 piles. I already got how to calculate it using 3 piles or h3. My main issue is using the list comprehension and returning the minimum value and also using Memoization to make sure I can run my code quick. I forgot to include that I am having an error when I run my h4 function. it is saying there is an issue with "|". I am new to haskell and can not debug because I am not sure what the problem is.

This is What I have below: My h3 function works fine. I need help mainly with my h4

```
h3 :: Int -> Integer
h3 0 = 0
h3 n = 2 * h3 (n - 1) + 1

h4 :: Int -> Integer
h4 0 = 0
h4 n = 2 * h4 (k) + h3 (n - k) | k <- [0..n-1]          
h4 n = minimum [2 * h4 (k) + h3 (n - k) | k <- [0..n-1] ]
```

My pseudo code is:

```
Function H4 (n): 
 if n < = 0 then return 0 
 else 
 for k from 0 to n - 1 
 calculate the value of 2 * H4 (k) + H3 (n - k) 
 create a list containing these n values 
 return the minimum value of the list.
```

I appreciate all the help and advise. I decided to improve my h4 function by adding the memoized function to make sure I get my output faster. When I run my h4 memoized function I get this error  :16:1: Not in scope: `memoized_h4'h3 :: Int -> Integer

```
--h3 function
h3 0 = 0
h3 n = 2 * h3 (n - 1) + 1

h4 :: Int -> Integer                --h4 function
h4 0 = 0
h4 n = minimum [2 * h4 (k) + h3 (n - k) | k <- [0..n-1] ]

main :: IO ()
main = print $ h4 4

--memoized h4
memoized_h4 :: Int -> Integer
memoized_h4 = (map 1H4 [0..] !!)
          where 1H4 0 = 0
1H4 n = memoized_h4 h3 (n - k) | k <- [0..n-1]        + memoized_h4 (2 * h4 (k) )
```

Comment: Writing code to do this for each of 3 or 4 disks is fine, but can you generalize it to 'n' disks? I'm pretty sure somebody had already worked that out. You can too. If you're still stuck, check [this - BUT ONLY WHEN YOU'VE GIVEN UP!](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TowerofHanoi.html)

Comment: Got it but my main issue is that I am getting an error when I run my h4 function. I am new to haskell and don't know how to fix it. The error has to do with " |".

Comment: Ok, you have to understand that haskell is declarative by nature. It doesn't follow execution in a sequential order of statements like Java or C. Since you are already computing this for `n`, comment out the third line in `h4`. Here's a [link](http://codepad.org/gN6e0xVg) if you need any help understanding what I mean.

Comment: As a side note, I believe the optimal solution for four piles or more is actually still completely unknown. See also the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanoi_tower#With_four_pegs_and_beyond).

Answer (score 3):

As to your syntax error, here's your code again, realigned:

```
h4 :: Int -> Integer
h4 0 = 0
h4 n =          2 * h4 (k) + h3 (n - k) | k <- [0..n-1]          
h4 n = minimum [2 * h4 (k) + h3 (n - k) | k <- [0..n-1] ]
```

It is easier to see what's missing, now. `|` here is a part of list comprehension, i.e. it is to appear inside `[ .... ]`. It can't appear on its own here.

Your 3rd line above is in error, but perhaps it isn't needed  at all.

(you really *should* include the error message in full, when posting on SO.  Please *always* do so in the future.)